# c# Constructing a class from its inherited classes object

Tags: c#, inheritance, refactoring, new-operator

I'm trying to implement a custom configuration class that would inherit `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection` as its base class.

```
public class MyConfigurationClass: System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection
{
   MyConfigurationClass()
  {
  }
}
```

I've been creating the class object like this:

```
MyConfigurationClass Config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Config") as MyConfigurationClass;
```

I want to move this into the constructor of my class so that instead of calling:

```
MyConfigurationClass Config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Config") as MyConfigurationClass;
```

I could call:

```
MyConfigurationClass Config = new MyConfigurationClass("Config");
```

For the same ressult.

Inheriting elements of `System.Configuration.ConfigurationSection` is critical.

Any suggestions?

Edit:
I am trying to initialize the default instance of this class using unity mapping and then use interfaces for the subsequent calls to this class. My interface is fixed and can not be modified and thus I can only use constructor to create the class...

Registration into unity framework is done from `unity.config` file:

```
<register type="MyNameSpace.IConfig, MyProject" mapTo="MyRealNameSpace.MyConfigurationClass, MyRealProject"> 
<lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" /> 
</register>
```

Comment: I don´t get your question. Can you please elaborate on what you expect? What should your code look like? What exactly do you want to hide?

Comment: I would like my initialization of `MyConfigurationClass Config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Config") as MyConfigurationClass;` to be done inside the constructor of `MyConfigurationClass` this means when I call `MyConfigurationClass Config = new MyConfigurationClass("Config");` it would create `MyConfigurationClass Config` the same way as using my current statement: `MyConfigurationClass Config = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Config") as MyConfigurationClass;`

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I like to add a static getter that fetches the configuration inside my section:

```
public class MyConfigurationClass : ConfigurationSection
{
        public static MyConfigurationClass Instance { get; } =
            ConfigurationManager.GetSection("Config") as MyConfigurationClass;

        // other configuration properties
}
```

And then I simply call `MyConfigurationClass.Instance.Property`

Comment: I am trying to initialize the default instance of this class using unity mapping and then use interfaces for the subsequent calls in my code. My interface is fixed and can not be modified and thus I can only use constructor to create the class...

Comment: If you are using some kind of DI (e.g. unity) you can register a factory that will resolve the  config type using a method: `container.RegisterFactory<IMyConfigurationClass>(f => MyConfigurationClass.Instance);`

Comment: I am trying to register it from unity.config `<register type="MyNameSpace.IConfig, MyProject" mapTo="MyRealNameSpace.MyConfigurationClass, MyRealProject">
      <lifetime type="Microsoft.Practices.Unity.ContainerControlledLifetimeManager, Microsoft.Practices.Unity" />
    </register>`

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9943216/unity-factory-via-xml